# Declaring method with extended classes

Tags: c++, syntax, function-prototypes

quick question on declaring functions. Lets say I have the following code:

```
class a{
    int var;
    /* stuff*/
}

class b : a{
    /* other stuff*/
}

class c : a{
    /* more other stuff*/
}

class d{
    myFunctionThatWantsTheIntNamedVar(SubClassOfClassA SomeClassUnknownAtCompileTime);
}
```

and myFunctionThatWantsTheIntNamedVar() wants just that, the integer(called var) declared in the base class of a. The function in class d may be passed an instance of class b or class c, which is not known at compile time (only at run time).

Is there a way I can concisely declare a function that could take either class b or c and get that same base variable?

What I have done in the mean time is declare two methods in class d, as follows:

```
class d{
    myFunctionThatWantsTheIntNamedVar(c aClassCInstance);
    myFunctionThatWantsTheIntNamedVar(b aClassBInstance);
}
```

which is fine and all, but the code in the two methods is IDENTICAL... And from my understanding of object oriented programming, if the code is identical you should be able to combine it into a better function.

Any thoughts on this? Just looking for best practices or other advice here, as I work at a small company and getting feedback can be hard at times.

EDIT: sorry, I had an error in my code, changed it from:

```
myfunctionThatWantsTheInNamedVar(a aClassAInstance);
```

to:

```
myfunctionThatWantsTheInNamedVar(c aClassCInstance);
```

my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide a public accessor method that gives access to the variable, and make sure you don't hide its name in class b and class c.

```
class a{
    int var;
    /* stuff*/
 public:
  const int& getVar() const { return var; }
  int& getVar() { return var; }
};
```

Then take a reference to an `a` in oyur function:

```
class d{
 public:  // you probably want a public member function
    myFunctionThatWantsTheIntNamedVar(const a& theA) {
      int n = theA.getVar();
}
```

Then you can call it with `b` or `c` instances:

```
b b0;
c c0;
d d0;
d0.myFunctionThatWantsTheIntNamedVar(b0);
d0.myFunctionThatWantsTheIntNamedVar(c0);
```

Bear in mind that in your code, the variable `var` is private, as well as the inhericance in classes `b` and `c`. For this to work, you would need to make the inheritance public:

```
class b : public a { .... };
class c : public a { .... };
```

Comment: This is what I was wondering if I could do, but haven't been able to test (a piece of hardware required to run the code is currently being fixed). Wasn't sure if I could pass an instance of a subclass to a method that has the superclass in the declaration. Good to know that this is kosher. Once the HW is fixed I can run the code and see if it's broken. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, one question actually. Why do you choose to make the pointer constant? I do not understand the benefit of this, but another poster reccomended this as well so I am curious to know why both of you did.

Answer (score 3):

```
class d{
    myFunctionThatWantsTheIntNamedVar(const a& anA);
}
```

If you really want to prohibit an actual instance of a, but allow any derived class, you can use Run Time Type Identification to throw an exception if it is actually an a, not a derived class.

If you have a pure virtual function in a that has no implementation (but requires b and c to provide implementations), then you can't even instantiate a, so no checking is required.  But, that is only if you had reason to do that -- I wouldn't suggest an artificial construct like that just for this.

Comment: Why did you suggest making the pointer constant? Another poster did as well and I am curious as to the benefit or requirement of this. Thanks!

Comment: `&` is a a reference not a pointer.  The main difference is with a reference its `anA.foo()` instead of `anA->foo()`.  I used the const and the reference so that it wouldn't _copy_ the object -- and in the case of derived class, _truncate_ the object to contain only the content of the base class, instead it would pass the object through, pretending to be an object.  And the const makes it non modifiable.

Comment: that makes great sense, thank you for the clear and concise response!

Answer (score 1):

Why not this:

```
class d{
   void myFunction(A a) {;}
};
```

if you say that the code for both of your functions is same, this means that they don't use anything which is different between classes C and B. In other words, you only use what's common to B and C, and that is actually class A.

Of course (A a) is just an illustration. You should declare argument as (const A& a) or (A* pA), depending on what you need. Also, I assume that `var` is somehow visible outside of its hierarchy, either by making it public or better, by encapsulating it in a public accessor.